# Wrong width and no borders with some rows in twitter bootstrap tables in print mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, responsive-design

Here is a table how it looks like in normal mode (desktop screen)
[image]

But when I try to print it (press ctrl + p) I see this:
[image]

But if I trying to display it in chrome emulator mode with print media it looks fine. Here is html of the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Этаж</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Общая площадь</td>
        <td>40.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Площадь кухни</td>
        <td>7.6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Жилая площадь</td>
        <td>40.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Год постройки</td>
        <td>1997</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Готовность</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Отопление</td>
        <td>Печное</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">Вода</td>
        <td>Холодная</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: [**check here**](http://www.bootply.com/hjeLiQPFzM) works here

Comment: It's weird. But when I removed col-md-* from td it works fine, but I can't control width of td in this case. Here is a live example http://resta.by/real_estates/prodazha-1-komnatnoy-kvartiry-d-senitsa-per-shkolnyy-dom-1-a-superpredlozhenie

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I don't why, but I haven't `position: static` rule

```
table td[class*="col-"],
table th[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  position: static;
}
```